# System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException while Deleting Record

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have following code in MVC w.r.t. EF 5.0 to delete an Item from a table

Earlier Its working fine. Not willing to use try...catch

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
  public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
  {
     using (OrderDBContext db = new OrderDBContext())
     {
        FoodItem food = db.FoodItems.Find(id);
        db.FoodItems.Remove(food);
        db.SaveChanges(); //Exception
     }
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
```

It should delete the record and redirect to "Index"

Comment: What is the exception message for your DbUpdateException?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be you have a related entity with your FoodItemId as a foreign key? For example let's say an ingredient which has an FoodItemId. That way you wouldn't be able to delete the fooditems before deleting all the ingredients unless you have a cascading delete set on your tables.

Comment: Thanks. Its true.